# Automation Anywhere Excel Loop

Tags: loops, rpa, automationanywhere

Does anyone know of an easy way to start an excel loop in Automation Anywhere at a row other than 1? (or two by using contains header option). I would like to start a loop at row 5 but everything I have tried thus far does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command - **Go to Cell** under Excel commands as explained below.

If you want to start from 5th row and 'A' column then before starting the excel loop:

1. Open spreadsheet
2. Select **Go to Cell** Command under excel commands
3. Select **Specific Cell** radio button
4. Provide the value of the Specific Cell as'A5'(which denotes  5th row and 'A' column)

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[How to write data to excel file in a loop starting from a specific cell](https://youtu.be/qnjHvzjlikY)

Answer (score 1):

Assign a loop count to a variable and if loop count is less than your desired row, continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily using the "Continue" command. When you are looping in the excel using "Each row in an excel Dataset", make use of system variable "counter". Since you want to start from row 5, that means you will have to skip the first 3 lines as you have marked the contains header as yes. Use the condition "if counter < 4 then continue" which will skip the first 3 lines.
[See below image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Pnr.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can go about it,

♦defining counter would be one way to go about it.and loop starts after 5.

♦you can use specific cell to begin your task and use times for loop(rest of the rows) and can iterate to rest of the rows.

♦other is run a smaller task where it would copy all cell from row 5 to a new sheet and you can use generic excelloop to do the same task. 
[this sheet can also be used to input something like "Success" and timestamp when loop finished that row to know its completed.]

Answer (score 0):

Look at this. I can tell you about G1ANT as I have worked on that. Just change the value of from, your excel loop will start from that value only.

```
addon msoffice version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0
excel.open ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\tlt.xlsx   inbackgound true
for ♥n from 5 to 100 step 1
excel.getrow ♥n result ♥rowInput
dialog ♥rowInput
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you cam use Excel Command.

**Excel Command**
1. Go to cell.
2. select your Excel Session
3. select specific Cells

- If you use Excel command in Loop Command
  you can use System variable "$Counter$"
  And **set Excel Command's select specific Cells to A$Counter$ / B$Counter$ etc.**